# PHP file wants to download, not display?

Tags: apache-http-server, php, lamp

I'm following these instructions exactly: http://wiki.debian.org/LaMp

But my test PHP file, created at:

```
# nano /var/www/apache2-default/test.php
```

wants to download in the browser, not display as a PHP file.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the AddHandler and AddType directives in your conf files. There's no need to make files executable when they really don't need to be.

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
```

Comment: Also (possibly) need a Loadmodule directive.

Answer (score 0):

You must tell apache that the file is a cgi script (don't forget to chmod +x it). Usually, apache is set up the think of everything in [wwwdir]/cgi-bin as a script, so just try putting it in there. Otherwise, you'll need something like this in your apache configuration (inside the VirtiualHost section):

```
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks! `chmod a+x` fixes the problem, but is this safe?

Comment: Not only safe, but also necessary: For a PHP script to generate any output, it must be executed. It's a program, after all.

Comment: @Tobias Plutat you don't need to execute it, @Xeonoactive's answer is correct. Apache recognizes it as a php file, and uses the php embeded in apache. Apache doesn't see as a CGI.

Comment: Following this method runs your PHP files as CGI scripts. While this is technically functional, it's not as efficient as running them under a PHP5 module. You'll probably notice that not many other sites run PHP as a CGI.